# mapped imshow does not work in subplot if different palette

Tags: image, matlab, matlab-figure, color-mapping

I found that apparently, a mapped version of [`imshow`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshow.html) function does not work in subplot. Is this by design?

The following script

```
rgb=imread('../FruitSample_small.png');
[ind,map]=rgb2ind(rgb,4);
figure
imshow(ind,map)
figure
subplot(5,1,1);
imshow(ind,map)
subplot(5,1,2);
imshow(ind==0)
subplot(5,1,3);
imshow(ind==1)
subplot(5,1,4);
imshow(ind==2)
subplot(5,1,5);
imshow(ind==3)
```

produces the following result

[image]

i.e. mapped version looks black. If I plot mapped version only (5 times) it looks ok. I.e. subsequent plotting apparently change the palette.

How to plot all these 5 images on same figure then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Colormap` is a property of the figure, not the axis. The second call to imshow resets the `Colormap` for the entire figure. [Here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2009/07/24/using-multiple-colormaps-in-a-single-figure/) is some more information and a Matlab file exchange solution to the problem. If you download the function described in that link, `freezeColors`, you can use it in your code like this.

```
rgb=imread('peppers.png'); % example image included in matlab
[ind,map]=rgb2ind(rgb,4);
figure
imshow(ind,map)

figure
subplot(5,1,1);
imshow(ind,map)
freezeColors % keep colors the same after other subplots are displayed
subplot(5,1,2);
imshow(ind==0)
freezeColors
subplot(5,1,3);
imshow(ind==1)
subplot(5,1,4);
imshow(ind==2)
subplot(5,1,5);
imshow(ind==3)
```

And the resulting second figure will look like this:

[image: fixed colors subplots example]